# WebView displays black screen

Tags: android, webview

I'm a little embarrassed to post this but I can't seem to figure out
where I'm going wrong.  I've looked at every example and every
tutorial and everything looks right to me.  Here's what I'm doing.  I
have a listview that when you click on an item it will take you to a
WebView that displays some static formatted text associated with that
list entry.

I had it all working with a TextView but I wanted to be able to use
HTML formatting for the text and figured the WebView was the way to
go.  Right now it is just supposed to display a generic link for
testing purposes but when the viewContent intent starts it just goes
to a black screen.  I can go back and pick another entry and it also
just shows the black screen.

I'm not sure what code you are going to want to see so here's the
viewSection class file and the viewsection.xml layout.

viewSection.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class viewSection extends Activity {

       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       WebView wv;

       setContentView(R.layout.viewsection);

       wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);
       wv.loadData("<a href='x'>Hello World! - 1</a>",
                                               "text/html",
                                               "utf-8");
   }
}
```

viewsection.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <WebView android:id="@+id/wv1"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to set `android:layout_height` on the `WebView` to `fill_parent`. I'm not sure if `WebView` supports `wrap_content`.

**EDIT**: You'll want to set the `LinearLayout` width and height to `fill_parent` as well.

Also, if you're using very light HTML styling, you can still use a TextView; there are samples in the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) sample app on how to do this (i.e. [StyledText.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/StyledText.html) and [Link.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/text/Link.html)).

Comment: I may look in to the Style text.  Changing the layout_height didn't fix it.  

Any other ideas?

Comment: See my edit re: LinearLayout width and height. In fact, you probably don't even need a LinearLayout, just put the WebView at the top level.

Comment: Right on. Taking out the LinearLayout fixed the problem. Thank you soooo much!

Comment: Actually webview does support wrap_content. But taking the webview out of the LinearLayout is voodoo. Also it would be nice if you included the version of the OS you are running the app on. It makes a big difference.

Comment: This fixed it for me too.. I used: 
WebView web (new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f));