# Why does the webview in Android go black?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

While using the emulator in Android Studio, an activity with a webview goes black on initiation. If I close the activity and start it again, the webview shows correctly. However, it goes black if I build the app and run it again (on the emulator only). Going black means instead of showing the web page, the entire webview object is black, as if it's a webpage with a black background. If I have 3 activities with webviews, it only happens once with the first webview loaded, regardless of the activity it belongs to.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181359/webview-displays-black-screen) question may help you.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna No. It's unrelated.